# How can I make CSS text like the one showed in the picture?

Tags: css

I'm making an ebook with Calibre, and the pages are based off xhtml and css files.
I want the page to maintain the same distance between paragraphs no matter what the size of the page is, but using padding as I have already tried doesn't track the size of the page and therefore messes up the aspect ratio, making some text overflow in the next page.

[Calibre view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8g2K.png)
[page I'm trying to replicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0hgR.jpg)

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* Styles for A Manual Of Occultism */
/*** IMPORT CSS FILES ***/
/*** center in page***/
.center {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  padding-top: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}
#main-title {
  text-align: center;
}
#sub-title {
  text-align: center;
}
#sub01 {
  padding-top: 2%;
}
#sub03 {
  padding-top: 10%;
}

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>A Manual Of Occultism</title>
  <link href="s0_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper">

    <div class="title" id="main-title">

      <h1>A MANUAL OF<br/>
OCCULTISM</h1>

    </div>

    <div class="text" id="sub-title">

      <div id="sub01">

        <p>BY <br/> “SEPHARIAL”</p>

      </div>

      <div id="sub02">

        <p>AUTHOR OF <br/> “THE MANUAL OF ASTROLOGY”, “ KABALISTIC ASTROLOGY”, <br/> “THE KABALA OF NUMBERS”, ETC.</p>

      </div>

      <div id="sub03">

        <p>LONDON <br/> WILLIAM RIDER &amp; SON, Ltd. <br/> 1914</p>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  Please use a code snippet to provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use flexbox to achieve this, i have also removed unnecessary tags.
You can play with justify-content and height of #wrapper to have exactly the effect that you want

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>A Manual Of Occultism</title>
        <link href="s0_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
                <h1>
                    A MANUAL OF<br />
                    OCCULTISM
                </h1>
  

            <div class="text" id="sub-title">
                    <p>
                        BY <br />
                        “SEPHARIAL”
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        AUTHOR OF <br />
                        “THE MANUAL OF ASTROLOGY”, “ KABALISTIC ASTROLOGY”,
                        <br />
                        “THE KABALA OF NUMBERS”, ETC.
                    </p>
            </div>

              <p>
                  LONDON <br />
                  WILLIAM RIDER &amp; SON, Ltd. <br />
                  1914
              </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
body{
    height: 100%;
}


#wrapper{
    height: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    
}
```

You can play with justify-content and height of #wrapper to have exactly the effect that you want

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! I'll totally play around with this later!